# Provide multiple Json responses from one entity

Tags: json, jpa, jackson

I use MYSQL, with JPA+Hibernate. I'd like to provide http responses by Jackson.
Sometimes I've to send back a Json just with username and id. For it @JsonIgnore would be a good solution. But other cases I've to send back the whole user with a lot of other data.
How can I do it the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for posting. I have too little XP to comment on your post.

- The best way is to have two REST endpoints for each requirement
- If that is not possible, based on the presence of an additional query
  parameter or path variable, you can code the controller to choose
  between two response entities.
- If it is necessary to use the same response entity, the remaining
  fields set to null, will not produce null attributes in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks. I can write more REST endpoints. My problem, I can't find out how to solve, I'd like to pass the entity object to client, without instantiate a DTO and set it's properties manually.
Hibernate gives back the same User entity at both endpoints, but how can I ignore properties in one case and don't ignore them in Json in the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seem to me I found the solution. Spring Projection.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections